# Exporting Angular Kendo UI Grid to Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, angularjs

I have a project where I using the Angular Kendo UI Grid and would like to be able to export the data to an excel document. I have looked at the ng-grid csv export but it appears one is required to use put in a plugins option but the Angular Kendo UI Grid does not have this. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kendo grid data export to a excel file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782116/kendo-grid-data-export-to-a-excel-file)

Answer (score 1):

Now you can just add the following to your grid options object:

```
toolbar: [ 'excel' ],
excel: {
        allPages: true,
        fileName: 'staticFileName.xlsx'
    }
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/excel-export#enable-excel-export

Comment: hi do you know answer for this by any chance?  thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785158/angular-kendo-grid-save-sorted-filtered-grid-in-a-variable

Answer (score 0):

There is a [kendo-grid-csv-download](https://github.com/uber-rob/kendo-grid-csv-download) project you can attempt to use.

Another way to accomplish this would be to create a server side page/URL in your language of choice (Python? NodeJS?) (Example: `example.com/downloadcsv?searchTerm=abc&filter=def`) and have it query the same API/URL that your Angular code queried to display the grid, then generate the CSV to download there.